# Extracting data lake data

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a data lake path as follows:

`SYSTEM/Data/Year/Month/Date/Hist/hist.parquet`

`hist.parquet` is present in every `Year/Month/Date/Hist` folder structure

I want to append all the parqets for all years as a single parquet file in `pyspark` in a differnt location.While doing so i.e before appending every single parquet I want to create a Date column `upload_date` reflecting the Year/Month/Date of the path it came from as YYYY-MM-DD.I also want to remove duplicated rows before each file append. Column names of every parquet file is the same

my `df` :-

| ID | Team | Flag | Action | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

```
for year_folder in year_folders:
    month_folders = dbutils.fs.ls(year_folder.path)
```

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can load data into dataframe first and then transform it.

```python
# first, create a dataframe with filepath.
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
df = spark.read.format('parquet').load('SYSTEM/Data/*/*/*/Hist/hist.parquet')
df = df.withColumn('filepath', input_file_name())
df = df.dropDuplicates() # dropping dups here is like dropping before appending

# then extract upload_date from filepath.
df = df.withColumn('upload_date', regexp_extract('filepath', r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', 1))
df = df.withColumn('upload_date', regexp_replace('upload_date', '/', '-'))
```

Comment: What is `input_file_name()`

Comment: each time it reads I want the path to be passed automatically to obtaint he date

Comment: The function returns file path for each record in spark dataframe.